# Ember template helper get-value-with-key

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

Does Ember have any template helper "get-value-with-key"
I found the below usage, but not sure what it does exactly ?

```
{{get-value-with-key item optionValuePath}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EmberJS - access properties of an object by arbitrary key in a template and have those properties bound using HTMLBars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676775/emberjs-access-properties-of-an-object-by-arbitrary-key-in-a-template-and-have)

Answer (score 2):

There is an Ember Get Helper for HTMLBars.
You might have to install the Package "ember-get-helper" if you are on ember < 2.1.

```
{{get object key}}
```

Comment: and why is my answer wrong? (My answer is correct...)

Comment: > You have to install the Package "ember-get-helper".
No he does not, `{{get}}` is a helper that is available in all ember apps (depending on version)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following object:

```
var obj = {
  "key1": {
    "subkey1": "hello world"
  }
}
```

Using Ember 3.18, to access "hello world" from the template, you can do:

`{{get obj 'key1.subkey1'}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build-in get helper. See docs here: [Ember Docs](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/get?anchor=get).

Usage example:

```
{{get object key}}
```

**Note** that the get helper will not be able to work on all JavaScript keys. For example, a key with a '.' will not work with the built-in get helper.

For example, if you have a valid JavaScript object like:

```
const example = {
    'example.pdf': 'pdf_url'
}

// You can access this key normally via
example['example.pdf']
```

however, this will not work in the get helper

```
{{get this.example 'example.pdf'}}
```

One solution is to create a helper that can support the types of keys you need to support. For example, I made a helper that can work on keys with a '.' by including '.' in the key name which are escaped like with ''.

```
{{get this.example 'example\.pdf'}}
```

The ember twiddle can be found here: [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6028235620f3c938ab2fc5d7166052d7?openFiles=templates.application%5C.hbs%2C)

Other Helpful Sources:

- [Dot notation for object keys with dots in the name](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/343)
- [How do I reference a field name that contains a dot in mustache template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901683/how-do-i-reference-a-field-name-that-contains-a-dot-in-mustache-template)